# Are magic constants documented? (eg __FILE__, __DIR__, etc)

Tags: crystal-lang

Accidentally, in the crystal lang github issues, I found out about __FILE__ and __DIR__ able to be used in and outside of macros. I don't remember reading about them. Have they been documented anywhere?

Comment: You mean documented as in [this?](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

Comment: I don't think they're documented, i've created an issue [here](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal-book/issues/136)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks, but that link you posted is for the GNU C preprocessor. The question was for the Crystal programming language, which has similar constants, but the two languages are different enough to need separate documentation.

Comment: @dgo.a: So it was, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation has been published: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/constants.html

Original issue: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal-book/pull/138

Comment: This is already documented https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/constants.html